# How can I convert MP3 files contained in the directory to ULAW files or any other raw format?

Tags: linux, mp3, asterisk

I am working on asterisk server which uses ulaw files to play the IVR on the call but our customers provide only mp3 files which need to be converted into ulaw, since I am new to this thing and am not aware of any such programs as well is there any way to achieve this in a faster way?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

we use lame to convert MP3 file Wav and then we provide this wav file to SOX which can produce required ULAW file.
I keep all the MP3 file in a directory and use the following commands on that directory.

```
for f in * ; do lame --decode $f ${f%.*}.wav ; done
for f in * ; do sox -V  ${f%.*}.wav -r 8000 -c 1 -t ul ${f%.*}.ulaw ; done
```

The above two commands will generate all the required ULAW files with 8000 Hz rate.
If you want to delete the WAV and MP3 files, you can use the following commands.

```
rm -f *.ulaw
rm -f *.mp3
```

Hope this will work for you too.

Comment: You can also recompile sox with mp3 support and do in one step.

Comment: @arheops don't I need lame in that case?

Comment: You can compile sox with liblame. It not compiled becuase of mp3 licensing issues. After that sox will understand mp3 and able convert directly